# Does Saleor support decimal order line quantity?

Tags: python, saleor

I want to use decimal quantity when create order, eg: 1.5, 2.7

Does Saleor support decimal or just integer quantity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only supports integers. You could open a github issue in the official repository with description of your use case to seek for an advice.